# bgcolor attribute not working with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi i am new to bootstrap i am facing a problem here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Progress Bar</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body bgcolor="red">

<p>Progress Bar</p>
<div class="container">
<div class="progress bg-danger">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success text-center" style="width:77%;">11
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to change background colour with

```
<body bgcolor="red">
```

but i don't know why this code is not working only working with inline css

```
style="background-color:red;"
```

is there any solution?

Comment: you have your answer, you need to use CSS, that property is obsolete since too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

> Bootstrap requires the use of the HTML5 doctype

From https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_bgcolor.asp

> The  bgcolor attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

So basically if you are using bootstrap, you need to define the background color in css as you are bound to use html5 doctype (which does not support bgcolor attribute of the body tag).

Hope this helps you to understand your situation a bit better.